# How to get article with comments using Drupal 8 REST?

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-8

As in the title. GET /node/1 returns article details with field called "comment" - but there are comment settings. GET /comment/1 returns comment with id 1 details. So how can I get article with comments list? Or just comments list for specific article?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new View with the following settings:

- Provide a REST export, and add a path.
- Make sure that *Format* is set to *Serializer* and *Accepted request format* is set to *json*
- Add a filter for *Content: Type (= [your format])*
- Add in *Fields* a field for *Content: Comments*